# git-filter-branch leaving untracked files

Tags: git

I am trying to use `git filter-branch` to refactor a repository.  I am trying to extract one directory from it.  Since I am not familiar with the command, I have been experimenting with a copy of the repository.

I found out that there is more than one way to achieve this. The command I used is

`git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter extract_dir -- --all`

(though since my case is fairly simple, it seems that `git subtree split` also works).

However, I am puzzled to note that in the filtered directory, a couple of files remain which had nothing to do with `extract_dir`. They are shown as untracked.

That's not exactly what I expected to see. It seems likely that it has something to do with those files appearing in the .gitignore file in the original repo. If so, I don't understand why they don't get removed like everything else.
(In my case I could easily clean up the untracked files manually, but it feels like that would be doing it wrong.)